# Как обработать событие асинхронного кода?

Tags: c#, события, websocket

Использую библиотеку WebSocketSharp (using WebSocketSharp;) для получения данных с сайта через вебсокет. (просто получение данных из интернета).
По сути просто клиентское приложение. Как обрабатывать события?

Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде сообщений между потоками. Опыта нет совсем. Сделал свои события, чтобы вызывать их в другом потоке. А обработчики и код запускать в основном потоке. Но не прокатило))))  С Invoke всё работает, но совсем не нравиться. Есть другие варианты!???
(ws.OnMessage в другом потоке. Там идёт открытие WinSocket, который онлайн всё время, поэтому нужен отдельный поток (так протокол вебсокет работает). Хотя с http тоже вроде также)
Что-то вроде:

```
                ws.OnMessage += (sender1, e1) =>
                {
                    .....
                    отправляем_свое_событие_в_основной_поток(моё_событие);

                };
            //А здесь уже обработчик, который исполнится в осн потоке:
            моё_событие+= {...}
```

Моё событие запускается через invoke. Как-то кривостью попахивает как сделать по-другому? Максимально просто. Получать OnMessage в основном потоке?
**Вот весь код.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebSocketSharp;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
        public string sMessage = "5";
        public string[] arr1=new string[500];
        public int i=0;
        //описываю собственное событие для передачи кода в основной поток.
        public delegate void SendMessageDelagate(string message);
        public event SendMessageDelagate Message;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //вешаю обработчик на своё событие
            Message += (s2) =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Код сработал нормально";
            };
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.example.com:5443/ws/eur@usd@deals");
                string s1 = "";
                ws.OnMessage += (sender1, e1) =>
                {

                    Action action = () => Message(sMessage);
                    s1 = e1.Data;
                    sMessage = "получен очередной пакет";
                    //через invoke вызываю своё событие в основном потоке.
                    Invoke(action);
                };
                ws.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD2** Действительно разные потоки. И Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId также разные.
[image: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/8/4/6952d39a95902ec00e1974c4bf610c73-full.jpg]

Comment: Какую именно сборку (библиотеку) вы использовали? Их с похожим названием на nuget несколько.

Comment: Если речь об [этом](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp), то события `On*` происходят в том же потоке. Никакой многопоточности нет. У этого класса есть асинхронные методы, но вы их не используете.

Comment: Использую WebSocketSharp 1.0.3-rc11 ______________________________________________  Событие 100% не в этом потоке. При попытке this.richtextbox1.text="блаблабла" получаю ошибку - "попытка доступа к элементу из другого потока"

Comment: Использую именно эту библиотеку ...sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client   Откуда у меня тогда другой поток, если его быть не должно? Connect происходит по нажатию на кнопку формы, может из-за этого?  И переменная тамже... Похоже из-за этого))) Говорю же 10 лет не кодил...

Comment: _Откуда у меня тогда другой поток_ - Вероятно, вы его сами создаёте. Пока не покажете больше кода, ничего конкретнее сказать нельзя. Но события этого класса происходят в том же потоке, в котором он был создан.

Comment: Номер потока можно посмотреть поставив точку останова и во время дебага открыв окно со списком потоков. Смысл спорить, если можно проверить. Так же можно вставить в нужные мета вызов кода, который получает номер потока и удостовериться. Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId

Comment: _Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId_ - Да, я именно так и проверил, что событие вызывается в том же потоке. На этом и основаны все мои комментарии.

Comment: Проверил с Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId. Действительно разные Id. Может, у вас консольное приложение? Версия студии у меня 2019, win10x64. И в окне отладки в потоках также видны разные потоки. Скрин выложу.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать контекст синхронизации, чтобы перенаправлять обработку событий в `UI` поток. Да, придётся создать класс `SomeWebService`, который будет интерфейсом для основного приложения, а в нём сокрыта конкретная реализация по работе с удалённым сервисом/сайтом и т.д. Чего не стоит делать - это точно работать внутри `Form1` с голыми классами всевозможных сокетов и т.д. В случае чего легче переписать саму реализацию класса, а для приложения может ничего не поменяться (в идеале).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace MultiThreading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ws = new SomeWebService("wss://stream.example.com:5443/ws/eur@usd@deals");
            ws.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
            ws.Connect();
        }

        private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("получен очередной пакет");
        }
    }

    public class SomeWebService
    {
        private readonly WebSocket _socket;
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext;

        public event EventHandler<MessageEventArgs> MessageReceived;

        public SomeWebService(string url)
        {
            _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
            _socket = new WebSocket(url);
            _socket.OnMessage += OnSocketMessage;
        }

        private void OnSocketMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            // Отправляем в UI поток, если экземпляр текущего класса был создан в UI потоке
            _synchronizationContext.Post(args => OnMessageReceived((MessageEventArgs)args), e);
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            _socket.Connect();
        }

        protected void OnMessageReceived(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Слишком сложно для меня. Пока в целях обучения сделаю "кривокод", как сам придумал, потом попробую сделать красиво.  Спасибо за ответ. Буду реализовывать свои события и их вызов через Invoke внутри событий WebSocket.